# How to change Required Disk space in install4j

Tags: install4j

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this

I am using install4j to create executable file, I need 2Gb of minimum space required , you can put this check ?.

I also want to check that machine should have 1.6X version of JDK installed, else I should terminate the installer. currently my installer is looking for JRE

thanks in advance

Sanjay

Answer (score 5):

For the disk space check, add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of your installer and set its script to

```java
if (SystemInfo.getFreeDiskSpace(context.getInstallationDirectory()) < 2000000000) {
    Util.showErrorMessage("You need at least 2 GB of free memory");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Then, set the "Failure strategy" property of the action to "Quit on failure":

[image]

For the Java version check, go to General settings->Java version and set the minimum version to 1.6:

[image]

If the installer cannot find a 1.6 JRE with that minimum version, it will display a dialog with an appropriate message.

Comment: is there any way that you can show this modified required disk space in the "installation location" screen?

Comment: Please see my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896803/install4j-modifying-having-a-custom-installation-location-screen/35898063#35898063