# Force installer to fail when ports are not available?

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to install an intranet application which requires an HTTP and HTTPS port.  I would like to test that these ports are available and warn the user/block the installation until they select unavailable ports.

The only avenue I see for this (besides custom code) is to ensure the windows service fails if the application cannot bind to needed ports, and use a Failure Strategy "Ask user whether to retry or quit on failure".  In the web server startup code, I use System.exit(1) if the server cannot bind to ports.  However, this does not appear to register as a failure to the installer - the installation proceeds without invoking the failure strategy.

What is the proper approach for signaling failure to the "Start a service" action?  Have other people taken an alternate approach to guaranteeing the installation uses available ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good alternate approach I've since found: add a custom code action:

```
List<Integer> takenPorts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int port : Arrays.asList(80, 443)) {
    java.net.ServerSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new java.net.ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        takenPorts.add(port);
    } finally { 
        if (socket != null) socket.close(); 
    }
}

if (takenPorts.isEmpty()) {
     return true;
}
else {
    String msg;
    if (takenPorts.size() == 2) {
        msg = "Ports 80 and 443 must be available for uDiscovery";
    }
    else {
        msg = "Port " + takenPorts.get(0) + " must be available for uDiscovery";
    }
    context.setVariable("portErrorMessage", msg);
    return false;
}
```

Good explanation of how to wire this up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722937/207161)

Comment: For greater flexibility, you can also display error messages with `Util.showMessage(msg, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);` directly in the script instead of using the failure strategy of the action.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me just an OK button, but with the behavior of "Ignore"

Comment: You could wrap that code in a loop and use `Util.showOptionDialog(msg, new String[] {"Retry", "Quit}, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE)` and if the result is 1 you return `false`. Then you could set the failure strategy of the action to "Quit on failure".

Comment: I ended up needing a different workflow, so I used the "Validation Expression" of the form - worked great.  Fantastic product, thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

All who are just getting an error dialog telling

> "com.install4j.runtime.beans.action.control.RunScriptAction failed"

I think that also was the one, Adam got:

In the srciptlet above the **variable** named **portErrorMessage** was set.

I also didn't realise that first. The trick is quite simple: You have to insert `${installer:portErrorMessage}` **in the field "Error message"**. Doing so, you don't need the `Util.showOptionDialog` described by Ingo, since that method call opens another, second dialog that has to be acknowledged first, after that the user would have to acknowloedge the dialog from install4j, too.