# Install4j: modifying/ having a custom installation location screen

Tags: install4j

My main target is to modify the required disk space showed in the "Installation location" screen as my software requires more than the spaces the installer counts. But from the properties of the screen, it does not seem that the required disk space can be configured from here. So, from the knowledge I have about Install4j, I have found the only way is to create a configurable from. For better understanding I have added the picture of the screen here:

[image]

now I was looking for a from component where I could set texts like marked in the circle. But I could not find any "text from component". Also How can I have Path selector like the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Install files" action has a "Installation size calculator" property. There you can modify the displayed installation size.

Comment: I changed that but had no idea that it also changes the properties in "installation location" screen. thanks